# Compilation error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender' on server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build

Getting error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender'
error on server but its working fine on my machine. Any idea what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20140725020714/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838090) and [this](http://This%20topic%20may%20have%20the%20answer%20you%20need:%20stackoverflow.com/questions/2009138) may help.

In essence, the steps to rectify the issue are as follows:

To work around this problem, replace the `<asp:Panel></asp:Panel>` tags that contain user controls in the .aspx page with `<div></div>` tags. The `<asp:Panel>` tag is rendered as an HTML `<div>` element.

To replace the `<asp:Panel></asp:Panel>` tags in the .aspx page with `<div></div>` tags:

1. Open the Web page that you want to modify.
2. At the bottom of the page, click **Code**.
3. On the Edit menu, click **Find**.
4. Click the **Replace** tab.
5. In the **Find what** box, type `<asp:Panel>`.
6. In the **Replace with** box, type `<div>`, and then click **Replace**. Replace all `<asp:Panel>` tags that contain a user control.
7. In the **Find what** box, type `</asp:Panel>`.
8. In the **Replace with** box, type `</div>`, and then click **Replace**. Replace all `</asp:Panel>` tags that contain a user control.
   On the **File** menu, click **Save**.

Comment: Link above is broken. This topic may have the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009138/asp-net-custom-control-unknown-server-tag

Comment: @lixon Thanks for noticing this.