# Issues with precompiled website and server control (parser error)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I am deploying our system to a brand new server that was previously untouched and having serious issues with .NET (the error points to server controls but i think this is a symptom rather than the problem)

Basically the VB6 code seems to work correctly but when moving over to the .NET I keep getting a parser error when loading the server control.

Like this

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Im quite sure that the server control isnt the issue and there isnt an issue with the compiled code. I have copied the code over from a working deployment on another server.

The code is organised as a WebSite rather than Web Application

The control is referenced at the top of the aspx page like so

```
<%@ Register Namespace="CustomWebControls" TagPrefix="Fastrack" %>
```

CustomWebControls is in the App_Code folder and is compiled into App_Code.dll

I think there is some issue with windows or IIS config stopping the reading of the compiled app_code.dll file. I have checked user permissions and allowed all to access i have manually copied over the dlls to the asp temp folders.

Other things tried

- reinstalled IIS
- reinstalled .NET
- checked web and machine.config files against known working ones
- checked iis installed components are correct

I'm completely out of ideas with this one and I'm not sure where to go next.
The stack trace disappears off deep into System.Web.UI and doesn't hint at any issues with our code at all (doesn't even seem its getting as far as loading it)

**Platform**

- Windows 2008 R2
- IIS 7
- .NET 4
- ASP.Net webforms

If anyone has any suggestions or would like some more info from me let me know.

Comment: Please review the accepted answer on the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009138/asp-net-custom-control-unknown-server-tag  Hope that helps.

Comment: I had seen that one and although it seems similar it doesnt really help me out. The application has been deployed to a number of live customers completely as is and without modification but on this new server we are having these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much ripping out of hair and sleepless nights the anser was a missing precompiledApp.config file!

The hardest ones often have the simplest answers!